# I have used functions to change the background color when selected in the bootstrap dropdown menu. But the color blinks and goes back to white

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have used functions to change the background color when selected in the bootstrap dropdown menu. But the color blinks and goes back to white.
These were the functions:

```js
const changeblue=()=>{
  
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='blue';
      showAlert("Blue mode has been enabled", "success");
  }
  const changepink=()=>{
   
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='pink';
      showAlert("Pink mode has been enabled", "success");
  }
  const changeyellow=()=>{
    
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
      showAlert("Yellow mode has been enabled", "success");
  }
```

The dropdown menu:

```html
<ul className="dropdown-menu">
<li><a className="dropdown-item" onClick={props.changeblue} href="/">Blue</a></li>
<li><a className="dropdown-item" onClick={props.changeyellow} href="/">Yellow</a></li>
<li><a className="dropdown-item" onClick={props.changepink}href="/">Pink</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: const changeblue=()=>{
  
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='blue';
      showAlert("Blue mode has been enabled", "success");
  }
  const changepink=()=>{
   
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='pink';
      showAlert("Pink mode has been enabled", "success");
  }
  const changeyellow=()=>{
    
      document.body.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
      showAlert("Yellow mode has been enabled", "success");
  }

Comment: suggest to create a gist or provide a sandbox example with the exact reproduction steps, regardless i think instead of doing this way u should hold your color as a state on the root level and pass this to your `body` styles, this way u wont have any side effect issues when hot reloading